# Python Pyautogui Wait For System to Repsond

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to develop a GUI Automation using pyautogui library. However, the system I am working on wait for a long time to load page by page. Apart from identifying the response time and set it as time.sleep. Is there any other to better deal with that? Great thanks!

Comment: If you are working in a web browser, I'd use Selenium or some other module that can control the web browser. These modules have functions for waiting until a page load is complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on a desktop software. I guess my current approach will stick with time.sleep first. Anyway, thanks for developing such a great tool! It is really easy to pick up. By the way, I will pick up Selenium later on!

Comment: Did you find a way to sort this out? I am having the same problem. I have an image that shows up multiple times before the page has loaded, but I want to click the last one